# XSL and XPATH issue

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I have this XML file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<TAVOLA>
    <ATOMO STATO="GAS"> <NOME>Elio</NOME> </ATOMO>
    <ATOMO STATO="SOLIDO"> <NOME>Oro</NOME> </ATOMO>
</TAVOLA>
```

and this XSL:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                version="1.0">
    <xsl:template match="ATOMO">
       <xsl:element name="@STATO">
         <NOME> <xsl:value-of select="NOME"/> </NOME>
       </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
```

I found this example on my book, at first when I execute it i get this error: `XTDE0820: Element name <@STATO> is not a valid Name`
In second I dont understand what does `<xsl:element>` do and how it works.

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/el_element.asp

Comment: I edited XML file but now I get this error : SXXP0003: Error reported by XML parser: XML document structures must start and end within
  the same entity.

Comment: @ginogino Please edit your question and add the expected result.

Comment: Please use more meaningful titles for your questions. "XSL and XPATH issue" is far too general - the title should describe the specific problem you are facing.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of:

```
<xsl:element name="@STATO">
```

try:

```
<xsl:element name="{@STATO}">
```

For explanation, see: *[attribute value template](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#attribute-value-templates)*.